# I ran `zsh -v` and now I have no shell history

Tags: shell, zsh

I just installed `zsh` today to try it out. I was trying to check my `zsh` version and I accidentally entered `zsh -v` which is the verbose option.

Now I can't seem to use reverse search on `history`. How do I turn it back on?

Comment: See the man page: "The sense of the single letter options may be inverted by using + instead of -."

Comment: Got it, thanks! History is still not working after `zsh +v` so I don't think it had to do with the verbose option.  However, I was able to get history back following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281833/zsh-shell-history-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ran `zsh -v`, this started a new instance of zsh. You aren't seeing your previous history because you're now interacting with a different process. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or run the command `exit` to exit this instance and go back to the parent instance.

You can use the `set` builtin to turn options on and off: `set +v` turns off the `verbose` option, `set -v` turns it on. But this has nothing to do with the history.